# Merging two branches into another without a new commit

Tags: git, merge

I'm having some issue merging two branches into another.

I have two feature branches with 1 commit ahead of master in each.

```
feature-branch-1 - 1 commit 'alpha' ahead of master 
feature-branch-2 - 1 commit 'beta' ahead of master
```

And I have a master branch with 1 commit.

```
master - 1 commit 'gamma'
```

I want to run something like this.

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-branch-1 --no-commit
git merge feature-branch-2 --no-commit
```

And end up with a master branch with three commits.

```
master - 3 commit 'gamma', 'alpha', 'beta'
```

The is sue is the first merge works. Then the second merge has this message.

> Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

How can I successfully merge these branches together?

Comment: This makes no sense. Your title says "without committing", but you specifically say you *want* commits to exist afterwards.  Do, or don't you, want individual commits? If you want three commits to exist on `master` after you merge two branches which each have *one commit*, then you just need a normal merge. Just do `git merge feature-branch-1; git merge feature-branch-2`. That's a *regular merge* with no extra options, to fast-forward `master` over the two branches. The option `--no-commit` obviously does *not* make a commit, so if you want commits, don't use it.

Comment: @meagar this does not work as desired, the first merge works, the second makes me manually commit a new commit, which is undesired.

Comment: That isn't how `git merge` behaves, unless your second commit cannot be merged cleanly, in which case you've asked the wrong question. The answer is **is** `git merge branch-1` followed by `git merge branch-2`, both of which behave identically and both of which create commits.

Comment: @meagar is there any quick way to merge `branch-1` into `master` then merge `master` into `branch-2` and merge `branch-2` into `master? All without having a specific merge commit?

Comment: `git checkout master; git merge branch-1; git checkout branch-2; git merge master; git checkout master; git merge branch-2`? Again, assuming these are all fast-forward merges, you don't need to worry about merge commits or special options to `git merge`. This is the completely vanilla normal use case for `git merge`. I'm still very unclear about what you're asking or why you think there would be a merge commit involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature-branch-1 --no-commit --no-ff
$ git merge feature-branch-2 --no-commit --no-ff
```

Comment: This doesn't commit anything. It leaves all of the files from the merge in the head.

Comment: ok. If you do just `git merge feature-branch-1`, `git merge feature-branch-2`. Is it work ?

Comment: Nope in that case the first merge is forwarded and the second merge is left uncommitted.

Comment: ok. If you `cherry-pick` two commits from  feature-branches then it works? `git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-branch1>`, `git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-branch2>`

Answer (score 0):

*Any* successful automatic merge done with `--no-commit` prints:

> Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

so you will see this for both `git merge` commands.

That said, though, Git has an "octopus" merge strategy for making a merge that ties several branches together all at once:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-branch-1 feature-branch-2
```

which in the ideal case does something like this, commit-graph-wise.  If we start with:

```
          o--o--o---o   <-- feature-branch-1
         /
...--o--o-----o----o    <-- master
         \
          o--o--o---o   <-- feature-branch-2
```

then (upon committing the octopus merge) we end up with:

```
          o--o--o---o     <-- feature-branch-1
         /           \
...--o--o-----o----o--o   <-- master
         \           /
          o--o--o---o     <-- feature-branch-2
```

There is, however, no real advantage at all over doing two separate merges:

```
          o--o--o---o         <-- feature-branch-1
         /           \
...--o--o-----o----o--o--o    <-- master
         \              /
          o--o--o------o      <-- feature-branch-2
```

The "hamburger" or "flying saucer" graph from the octopus merge gives you no abilities that you lack when using the "boat" graph from the two-separate-merges method.